# Replace part of a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I used regular expressions to get a string from a web page and part of the string may contain something I would like to replace with something else. How would it be possible to do this? My code is this, for example:

```python
stuff = "Big and small"
if stuff.find(" and ") == -1:
    # make stuff "Big/small"
else:
    stuff = stuff
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
>>> stuff = "Big and small"
>>> stuff.replace(" and ","/")
'Big/small'
```

Answer (score 21):

Use the `replace()` method on string:

```
>>> stuff = "Big and small"
>>> stuff.replace( " and ", "/" )
'Big/small'
```

Answer (score 9):

You can easily use `.replace()` as also previously described. But it is also important to keep in mind that strings are immutable. Hence if you do not assign the change you are making to a variable, then you will not see any change.
Let me explain by;

```
    >>stuff = "bin and small"
    >>stuff.replace('and', ',')
    >>print(stuff)
    "big and small" #no change
```

To observe the change you want to apply, you can assign same or another variable;

```
    >>stuff = "big and small"
    >>stuff = stuff.replace("and", ",")   
    >>print(stuff)
    'big, small'
```