# Insert words into string starting from specific index

Tags: python-3.x

I have string that looks like this : 'Foo dooo kupa trooo bar'.

I know the start and end point of word kupa and I need to wrap it with this : `<span> </span>.`

After this operation i want my string to like like this : `Foo dooo <span>kupa</span> trooo bar`

I cannot find any good built-in methods that can help so any help would be  nice.

Comment: what is  the difference between your input string and your output string? they look identical to me...

Comment: i want to wrap it with html tag and it didn`t show until i changed it to code sample, my foult

Answer (score 0):

basically there are two options:

```
import re
strg = 'Foo dooo kupa trooo bar'

match = re.search('kupa', strg)
print('{}<span>{}</span>{}'.format(strg[:match.start()], strg[match.start():match.end()], strg[match.end():]))
```

or (the first expressioin would be a regex, if the pattern were a little more complicated):

```
print(re.sub('kupa', '<span>kupa</span>', strg))
```

Answer (score 0):

The output string and the input string are the same.....

Anyway I think you want to replace part of your string, so have a look at this answers:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10037749/4827890
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723785/4827890