# Python: Replacing arbitrary substrings with substrings

Tags: python, string, indexing, slice

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I've been struggling with this for weeks now.

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a particular substring within an arbitrary string with another particular substring.

IE:

If I get user to type in an arbitrary string, I want to replace any instance of "MAA" with something like "UOP".

**My code:**

```
cstring = input("Enter a character string: ")


for i in cstring:
    if ((i != 'M') and (i != 'U') and (i != 'I')):
        break
    else:
        if (cstring[-1] == 'I'):
            cstring = cstring + 'U'
        if (cstring[:1] == 'M'):
            cstring = cstring + cstring[1:]
        if ('III' in cstring):
            cstring = cstring[:i] + "U" + cstring[i:]
        if ('UU' in cstring):
            cstring = cstring[:i] + '' + cstring[i:]
        break
print(cstring)
```

Thanks!

Comment: as for why your code doesn't work, you have a `break` statement in both conditionals, so the for loop is forced to stop after the first iteration.

Comment: As Tadhg has mentioned, don't use `break`, just use `continue`.  This doesn't look like an assignment to me though, looks more like research/science code potentially for some kind of user-input based config or something.

Comment: It's not an assignment question, but a tutorial one. I've been advised that the cstring.replace() method won't work for this, and that I should instead use slicing so as to maintain proper index conformity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace part of a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037742/replace-part-of-a-string-in-python)

Comment: But thanks for the break problem haha. I totally didn't notice that.

Comment: This is based off the MU game out of "Godel, Escher, and Bach: an Eternal Golden Braid" by Douglas R Hofstadter

Comment: `i` represents each character in the string so it can't be used for slicing, to keep an index and the character use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) like `for i, char in enumerate(cstring):` then keep a distinction between the index `i` and the character `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String replace` method like this:

`cstring.replace("MAA,"UOP")`

However, if you want to code it yourself, this works:

```
cstring = input("Enter a character string: ")


for i in range (0, len(cstring)):
    if (len(cstring[i:]) >= 3 and cstring[i] == "M" and cstring[i+1] == "A" and cstring[i+2] == "A"):
        cstring = cstring[:i] + "UOP" + cstring[i+3:]
print(cstring)
```

Comment: your code that does it manually will raise an index error if `"M"` is one of the last 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

As other users have noted you can use `str.replace`.  Here are some other options:

#### Regular Expressions

This is probably the way to go since you'll be able to replace any regex with your replacement string with all the advantages of the various re flags.

```
import re
re.sub("MAA", "UOP", cstring)
```

#### Validate String on Input

If your end goal is to work with a string with some simple replacements, you can also just try to enforce this in the input level.  i.e.

```
cstring = input("Enter a valid character string: ")
while bool(re.search("invalid_characters_regex", cstring)):
    print("Your input contained invalid characters, please try again.")
    cstring = input("Enter a valid character string: ")
```