# How to remove "1" from the backside of the URL using python?

Tags: python-3.x

https://www.amazon.com/I3565-A453BLK-PUS-Dell-Laptop-Dual-Core-Processor/product-reviews/B07BLPHRX9/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_srt?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&filterByStar=positive&pageNumber=1&sortBy=recent

I need to remove last "1" residing in the URL so that I can implement it in my code.
Is there any method in the python to remove that "1"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace part of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037742/replace-part-of-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @Georgy how is it same as I have find all the related questions, studied them and found not a single relavent answer. Then posted the questions.
The question you are referring is containing loops. where as my case doesn't need loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a= "https://www.amazon.com/I3565-A453BLK-PUS-Dell-Laptop-Dual-Core-Processor/product-reviews/B07BLPHRX9/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_srt?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&filterByStar=positive&pageNumber=1&sortBy=recent"

b= a.replace("pageNumber=1","pageNumber=")

print(b)
```

This is how you can do. Use string.replace() to replace anything in the string.

[Check here for replace method and its use](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-string-replace-method-replacing-python-strings/)