# Replace Characters In JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON object similar to the following:

```
{"First":[{"FirstKey1" : "FirstValue1\n", "FirstKey2" : "FirstValue2\n"}], "Second":[{"SecondKey1": "SecondValue1"}]
```

I want to change the `\n` to be `</br>`.
I have tried the following code, however, it doesnt work as the "Values" are contained within a list:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
   dict1[key] = value.replace("\n", "</br>")
```

This would work for the following dict where there isnt any "Lists" involved:

```
dict1 = {"test1" : "test1\n, test1\n,test1", "test2" : "test2\n"}
```

How can i make this work where the Values of Keys are Lists? 
I would like to do this in a "traditional" Python way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace part of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037742/replace-part-of-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but it severely lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by doing the following:

```
dict1 = json.dumps(dict1).replace("\\n","</br>")
```